# How to Read Pen Drives connected through OTG?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, usb-drive

Here is my code of my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv=findViewById(R.id.chckExternal);

    filter();
}
```

this is my code of filter files...

```
//--------------------Filter files----------------
 public  ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root) {
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for(File singleFile : root.listFiles())
    {
        if(singleFile.isDirectory()   && !singleFile.isHidden() ) {
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
        } else if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || 
singleFile.getName().endsWith(".MP3")) {
            al.add(singleFile);
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

This is the method to set the filter values in listview.

```
public void filter(){
    ArrayList<File> 
arrayList=findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    ArrayList<String>  convertedItemsList=new 
ArrayList(arrayList.size());
    for(int j=0;j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
      convertedItemsList.add(arrayList.get(j)
 .getParentFile().getName().toString());
    }

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new 
  ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
  convertedItemsList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
}
```

This code is able to read the files from internal storage of device but unable to read from the external storage like OTG and removable Sd card....

Comment: You need to use [`StorageManager.getStorageVolumes()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager#getStorageVolumes()) to list all available drives, then obtain permission with [`StorageVolume.createAccessIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume). After that You have to operate on documents provider instead of `Files`.

Comment: IOW, you have no direct read-write access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.